# WePay Delayed Payment with auto_capture (WePay Payment Gateway)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, payment-gateway

I am working on an application integrating wepay's delayed payment functionality into it. While accessing /checkout/create api call on stage.wepay.com, it takes to payment page and the final response always gives the state as **authorized**.
I had passed the auto_complete parameter as false and the expected return state was **reserved** but instead wepay is always returning the **authorized** state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems wepay always sends the response as authorized state. It will be returned as reserved only if we make a second request. This is the response I got from the wepay team :

> Ticket #149740: Delayed payment issue on stage.wepay.com
>
> Your request (#149740) has been updated .
> To review, comment and continue the discussion, follow the link below:
> http://support.wepay.com/tickets/149740
>
> Chris Chen, Sep 08 09:50 am (PDT):
>
> Hi xxxx,
>
> That's actually how it's supposed to work. Authorized will turn into reserved. Very rarely will >something fail after Authorized except for something like fraud. This is a very very small fraction >of transactions.
>
> We recommend you consider Authorized as successful.
>
> Thanks.
>
> Chris